# how to pass queue length from ppp to IP layer in Inet 3.6

Tags: networking, omnet++, ipv4

I'm working on implementing a new feature in Inet 3.6 framework, I'm working on Omnet++ 5.1.

I'm looking for a way to get the ppp module's out-queue length (router.ppp[1].queue.l2queue) while preparing the IP Header in IPv4 module (before passing the packet to the lower layer).
I thought of passing the queue length using the attached control-Info to the packet, but that would work only for packets coming from a lower layers to the IP layer, and in my case, I'm passing the packet from the IP to a lower layer.

Do you have any ideas on how to pass this info from a lower layer to a higher layer (ppp to IP)?

Comment: PPP uses the NCP for things like that.

Comment: Thank you,
But according to Inet 3.6 manual, NCP is not supported in Inet. Page 15 in the manual: "There are no NCP messages, the network layer protocols are configured by other means."

https://doc.omnetpp.org/inet/api-3.6.0/inet-manual-draft.pdf

Comment: Then that really isn't PPP because NCP is part of PPP. PPP has three layers, and one of those is NCP.

Comment: I found a way to do that.
Omnet++ uses Signals for communication between different modules.